# Simplify a weighted average with enumerations as weights

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, average, multisets

Could you help me simplify the following expression:
$$\forall n_0 \ge 0, \forall m_1,m_2 \gt 0, \forall k_1 \in [[0,n_0m_1]],\forall k_2 \in [[0,n_0m_2]],$$
$$\overline{k_0}_{(n_0,m_1,m_2)}(k_1,k_2) = \frac{\sum_{k_0=0}^{n_0} w_{k_0} k_0}{\sum_{k_0=0}^{n_0} w_{k_0}},$$
$$w_{k_0} = \binom{m_1-1}{k_1-k_0}_{n_0+1} \binom{m_2-1}{k_2-k_0}_{n_0+1}$$
with the notations:
$$\biggl(\binom{n}{k}\biggr) = \binom{n+k-1}{k}$$
$$\biggl(\binom{-n}{k}\biggr) = (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$$
$$\binom{n}{k}_{m} = \sum_{i=0}^n \biggl(\binom{-n}{i}\biggr) \biggl(\binom{n}{k-im}\biggr)$$
(actually, $\bigl(\binom{n}{k}\bigr)$ is the [number of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) and $\binom{n}{k}_{m}$ is a kind of generalized [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), with $\binom{n}{k}_{2} = \binom{n}{k}$ but giving different triangles with for example [m=3](https://oeis.org/A027907) or [m=4](https://oeis.org/A008287))

I tried to use [falling and rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) but it didn't led me as far as I'd want to.
I also read about [Dixon's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity) and [MacMahon Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacMahon_Master_theorem) but I don't see how to use them.

---

My goal would be to compute the corresponding function $p_0$ (with $[x]$ being some rounding function): $$\forall p_1,p_2 \in [0,1], p_0(p_1,p_2)=\lim_{n_0,m_1,m_2 \to \infty} \frac{\overline{k_0}_{n_0,m_1,m_2}([p_1 n_0 m_1],[p_2 n_0 m_2])}{n_0}$$

I computed it for some large values of $n_0,m_1,m_2$ and it seems to converge.

---

To add some background, this is my current attempt to answer [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351004), which I will edit soon to explain how I found this expression.

To summarize, it's an attempt to compute a good *a priori* probability for $P(S|A\&B)$, with A and B being independent and knowing the values of $P(S|A)$ and $P(S|B)$ (and maybe $P(S)$)

Comment: Hm, the first sum $m_{n_0, m_1, m_2}(i_1, i_2) = \frac{i}{n_0}\frac{\sum w_k}{\sum w_k} = \frac{i}{n_0}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope it was a stupid mistake, thanks! I corrected it.